# Is the degree m taylor polynomial, A polynomial field over R^n?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

$x \in R[x]$, $x^2 \in R[x]$, since it is a field any operation * b/w these two's results must also be in $R[x]$, but $x^-1$ is not in $R[x]$

So clearly polynomials do not form a field.

However, Professor Ghrist says that it is a polynomial field at 1:04 of this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pePJKl6EFDo&t=63s

Am I missing something?

Comment: That's not what "field" means here.  He's talking about something inspired from "vector fields."

Comment: Akin to this:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field  Change the point, change the vector.  He is saying "change the center, change the Taylor polynomial."  That is vector-field-like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a really bad expression since it tempts the listener to confuse two totally different issues. What he mean by "polynomial field" has nothing to do with "fields" in algebra. Here he draws an analogy to vector fields: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field

A vector field assigns to a point a vector, in yours/his case the "polynomial field" assigns to a point a polynomial: the Taylor expansion around the point.

That's why he calls it a "field". But this is not standard usage of language, no algebraist would use this "terminology" here, but the informal analogy is ok.

Comment: Your answer also argues that it is actually *not* a really bad expression.

Comment: ...I'm a algebraist :) I should be more precise: analogy ok, denotation horrible

Comment: Oh man, so you're saying the last hour of confusion could have been avoided if some people just named things properly

Comment: I couldn't have said it better.

Comment: I agree: very poor name for that. +1